# CSS img hover extend black bar

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a special hover for a website.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

[image: Block on Homepage]

[image: Block hover]

4 blocks, all responsive with a black bar with 70% of opacity with the main text.

Then when I hover a block, the black bar fill all the space at the bottom and reveals 2 or 4 buttons.

[image]

Maybe something like this :

```
<div class="image-block">
    <div class="image1">
        <span class="black-bar">SOME TEXT</span>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <span class="black-bar">SOME TEXT</span>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image3">
        <span class="black-bar">SOME TEXT</span>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image4">
        <span class="black-bar">SOME TEXT</span>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        <button class="special-button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for the CSS I really don't know how to do this. What is the simplest and best way to do this with something fully responsive ?

Thanks !

Comment: I mean scalable yeah. Like if you resize the screen it will look the same until it's too small to show properly the button so each block would be on the top of the other

Comment: Try giving dimensions width + height to the semitransparent black box.
At first make height as much as it shows only 1 row with buttons and when hovering, increase the height to show also the other row.
Also, add the property `overflow: hidden` to the black box.

Comment: Here's something: https://jsfiddle.net/6j01xjpd/, you can go on from there. Use media queries to target different screen sizes and breakpoints.

Comment: If you want buttons to appear when black bar is hovered -> put buttons into `.black-bar` div, make them `display: none` and style `.black-bar:hover .special-button` with `display: inline-block`. Create codepen snippet if you want live examples.

Comment: I will try a codepen tomorow and update the code, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure `css` option. If I missed something just let me know. I had to adjust your markup a little bit.

```css
.image-block{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image1, .image2, .image3, .image4{
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image1, .image4{
  height: 100px;
}

.image2, .image3{
  height: 200px;
}

.black-bar{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  bottom: calc(50% - 15px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.black-bar button{
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.black-bar p{
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.image1:hover .black-bar, .image2:hover .black-bar, .image3:hover .black-bar, .image4:hover .black-bar{
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image1:hover .black-bar button, .image2:hover .black-bar button, .image3:hover .black-bar button, .image4:hover .black-bar button{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="image1">
        <div class="black-bar">
          <p>SOME TEXT</p>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <div class="black-bar">
          <p>SOME TEXT</p>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="image3">
        <div class="black-bar">
          <p>SOME TEXT</p>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image4">
        <div class="black-bar">
          <p>SOME TEXT</p>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
          <button class="special-button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Added an animation via tiny bit of `calc` magic.

```
bottom: calc(50% - 15px);
```

Comment: Perfect ! But is it possible to have a pure css animation like mikele https://jsfiddle.net/gqxav4e3/1/ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you effort ! I've made some change on it to fit my theme and it's perfect. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the code below (I had to use jQuery) or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqxav4e3/1/)

```js
$('.text').mouseenter(function () {
 $('.hovering').animate({'height': '200px'}, 'slow');
});
$('.image').mouseleave(function () {
 $('.hovering').animate({'height': '100px'}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.hovering {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 100px; 
  position: absolute;
}
button, .text {
  display: block;
  width: 130px; height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
<div class="hovering">
   <span class="text">Text here</span>
   <button>Button here</button>
</div>
</div>
The black box shrinks when mouse leaves the image
```

Comment: This is a really good start thanks ! But what about the second picture with more height ?  You have only one way with the margin top ?